# Making the span stop animating while the flashlight is intersecting with the span

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

This is a javascript issue. We have an assignment where we are supposed to express an emotion through typography. I have made a flashlight effect attached to the mouse where you move around the mouse to look for the letters (the spans). I want the spans to stop (with a delay for around 5seconds), but I don't know why the spans are like unstoppable or something because I can't make them stop animating. They stop animating when I move around the flashlight, but not when the flashlight is just on them. I know that the code is super messy (we where provided with a template to modify) but please let me know if you need me to explain something that seems messy.

I've tried to modify the loop function, tried console.log out where it's moving but I don't know where the problem is.

```
// The state should contain all the "moving" parts of your program, values that change.
let state = Object.freeze({
    latestKey: undefined,
    isMoving: false, // Flag for tracking the state of moving animation
    trackingTime: 0, // Tracking the time for moving animation
});


// The settings object contains all of the "fixed" parts of your sketch, 
// like static HTMLElements, paramaters or thresholds.
const settings = Object.freeze({
    textElement: document.querySelector("#text"),
    flashLight: document.querySelector("#flashlight"),
    range: 20, // Setting a range for the spans to move around in 
    movementDuration: 1000, // Duration for the spans movement animation
});


/**
 * Update the state object with the properties included in `newState`.
 * @param {Object} newState An object with the properties to update in the state object.
 */

function updateState(newState) {
    state = Object.freeze({ ...state, ...newState });
}


/**
 * Return `num` normalized to 0..1 in range min..max.
 * @param {number} num
 * @param {number} min 
 * @param {number} max 
 * @returns number
 */

function scale(num, min, max) {
    if (num < min) return 0;
    if (num > max) return 1;
    return (num - min) / (max - min);
}


/**
 * Return `num` transformed from the normalised 0..1 form back to the min..max form.
 * @param {number} num
 * @param {number} min 
 * @param {number} max 
 * @returns number
 */

function toAbsolute(num, min, max) {
    if (num < 0) return min;
    if (num > 1) return max;
    return (num * (max - min)) + min;
}
// Function for generating a random location for each span
function getRandomLocation() {

    // Generating a random x and y location and subtracting 100 from the innerWidth and height
    // so that the random location is in the area of our browser
    const xPosition = Math.min(Math.max(100, Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - 100)));
    const yPosition = Math.min(Math.max(100, Math.random() * (window.innerHeight - 100)));

    // Returning the x and y location through left and top
    return { left: xPosition, top: yPosition };
}

// Function for making the spans (letters) move around
function spanMovementEffect() {
    const { range } = settings

    // Getting all the span elements
    const spans = settings.textElement.getElementsByTagName("span");

    // Iterating through every span...
    for (const span of spans) {

        //...and generating random values for the movement of the spanson the X and Y axis for each span
        const transformX = Math.random() * (2 * range) - range;
        const transformY = Math.random() * (2 * range) - range;

        //...and setting the movement to take one second
        span.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in-out";

        //... and setting the position of the spans to the transformX and Y
        span.style.transform = `translate(${transformX}px, ${transformY}px)`;
    }

}

// Function for setting the flashlight's position to our cursor position
function flashlightMovement(event) {

    // Getting the cursors position and storing it in flashligtX and Y
    const flashlightX = event.clientX;
    const flashlightY = event.clientY;

    // Setting the flashlights position to be in the cursors position
    settings.flashLight.style.left = `${flashlightX}px`;
    settings.flashLight.style.top = `${flashlightY}px`;

    // Making the flashlight to be in the center of the cursor
    settings.flashLight.style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%)`;
}


// Function for starting the movement of the spans
function startMovement(span) {
    let { isMoving } = state;
    const { movementDuration } = settings;

    // If the isMoving is false...
    if (!isMoving) {
        //...update the trackingTime with the current time
        updateState({ trackingTime: performance.now() })
    }

    // Function for updating the movement animation
    function updateMovement(timeStamp) {

        const elapsed = timeStamp - state.trackingTime; // Calculates the time since animation has started
        const progress = Math.min(elapsed / movementDuration, 1); // Calculates the progress of the animation with a value between 0 and 1

        // If isMoving is false...
        if (!isMoving) {

            //...start moving!!
            span.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in-out";
            span.style.transform = "translate(0)";

            // If progress is less than 1...
            if (progress < 1) {

                // Continue the animation loop
                requestAnimationFrame(updateMovement);

                // Otherwise...
            } else {

                //...animation is not in progress and the span should stay in its place
                span.style.transform = "translate(0)";
            }
        }
    }

    // Telling it that the movement animation is ongoing
    updateState({ isMoving: true, trackingTime: performance.now() });

    // Continueing the animation loop
    requestAnimationFrame(updateMovement);
}

// Function for stoping the span movement animation
function stopMovement(span) {
    span.style.transition = "none";
    span.style.transform = "translate(0)";
    updateState({ isMoving: false });

}

function checkWithinRange(span) {
    const flashlightRect = settings.flashLight.getBoundingClientRect();
    const spanRect = span.getBoundingClientRect();

    const flashlightCenterX = flashlightRect.left + flashlightRect.width / 2;
    const flashlightCenterY = flashlightRect.top + flashlightRect.height / 2;

    const spanCenterX = spanRect.left + spanRect.width / 2;
    const spanCenterY = spanRect.top + spanRect.height / 2;

    const distance = Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(spanCenterX - flashlightCenterX, 2) +
        Math.pow(spanCenterY - flashlightCenterY, 2)
    );

    return distance < 70;
}




// Function for checking the distance between the flashlight element and the spans and set their visibility depending on the range
function checkSpanVisibility() {

    // Getting all the spans
    const spans = settings.textElement.getElementsByTagName("span");

    for (const span of spans) {
        const isWithinRange = checkWithinRange(span);

        const isMoving = getComputedStyle(span).transition !== "none";

        if (isWithinRange && isMoving) {
            stopMovement(span);
            console.log("Movement stopped");
        } else if (!isWithinRange && isMoving) {
            startMovement(span);
            console.log("Movement started");
        }

        span.style.visibility = isWithinRange ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    }
}

let frameCounter = 0;
let updateFrequency = 60;

/**
 * This is where we put the code that transforms and outputs our data.
 * loop() is run every frame, assuming that we keep calling it with `window.requestAnimationFrame`.
 */

function loop() {
    const { isMoving } = state;
    const { textElement, growthFactor } = settings;

    if (frameCounter % updateFrequency === 0) {
        spanMovementEffect();
        console.log("Im still moving!")
    }

    frameCounter++;

    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}


/**
 * Setup is run once, at the start of the program. It sets everything up for us!
 */

function setup() {

    document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
        updateState({
            key: {
                code: event.code,
                key: event.key,
                pressed: performance.now()
            }
        });

        // If the key pressed is has the value 1, meaning the key pressed it not shift, enter etc
        if (event.key.length === 1) {
            const { top, left } = getRandomLocation();

            // Create spans 
            const span = document.createElement("span");

            // Setting the key pressed to the span
            span.textContent = event.key;
            span.style.position = "absolute";
            span.style.top = `${top}px`;
            span.style.left = `${left}px`;

            settings.textElement.style.visibility = "hidden";

            // Adding the span to the text element
            settings.textElement.appendChild(span);
        }
    });

    document.addEventListener('pointermove', (event) => {
        flashlightMovement(event);
        checkSpanVisibility();
    })

    document.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
        // Nothing!
    });
`
    loop();
}

setup(); // Always remember to call setup()!
```

Here is a picture of the output so you can visually see my program:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem from what I can see is that your `checkSpanVisibility()` function is only run when the `pointermove` event is fired here:

```
document.addEventListener('pointermove', (event) => {
    flashlightMovement(event);
    checkSpanVisibility();
})
```

And your `stopMovement()` function is only called within `checkSpanVisibility()`. That's why it only works when your mouse is moving. If you want spans to stop in the light no matter what, `checkSpanVisibility()` should be run on every frame (i.e., within your `loop()`).